# I can't initialize my array of objects outside of my event method

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I want to make a program that will create a Array of objects that will store the number of times a user has clicked a button. 
I ask the user what their id number is and then access their element of the array and update their button clicks.
The problem is that it won't let me set 
surveyor[0] = new Surveyors();
surveyor[1] = new Surveyors();     unless I put the code in my attemptUpdateActionPerformed method, but I need to set it up outside of the method so it will not reset itself each time the button is clicked. There is a lot of extra stuff in here, but I think the main problem lies in the method. Sorry for the sloppiness.

```
package guildquality;


import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Surveyors [] surveyor = new Surveyors[10];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public int id;

     /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
   surveyor[0] = new Surveyors();
   surveyor[1] = new Surveyors();
    id = 0;

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        attemptUpdate = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        attemptUpdate.setText("Attempt");
        attemptUpdate.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                attemptUpdateActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addComponent(attemptUpdate)
                .addContainerGap(308, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(173, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(attemptUpdate)
                .addGap(104, 104, 104))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void attemptUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
     System.out.print("what is your id?");
      id = scan.nextInt();
      surveyor[id].setAttempts();
      System.out.print(surveyor[id].getAttempts());
          // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                             

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton attemptUpdate;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}


at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:497)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
at guildquality.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:19)
at guildquality.Surveyors.<init>(Surveyors.java:17)
at guildquality.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the main method. It will run once and before the eventhandler can run.

Comment: It gives me the error non-static variable Surveyor cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: My bad, I did not realize Surveyor was not static, use @WillShackleford's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should put code you want to initialize non-static class variable once in the constructor.

eg.

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();

    // More initialization here.
    surveyor[0] = new Surveyors();
    surveyor[1] = new Surveyors();
}
```

Comment: it will let me run it now, but I will get a run time error. Here is my code now.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError @WillShackleford

Comment: StackOverflowErrors are typically caused by too many recursive function calls but I don't see any in your code. Can you edit your question to paste in the full stack trace or at-least the first 10 lines or so?

Comment: I just posted it to the bottom of my question. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hey I actually just found the problem. It was in my Surveyor class. Thank you for all the help Will! @WillShackleford